# Which are the most important directories to backup on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, backup, live-backup

I'm running an Ubuntu 9.10 Linux server. I'm trying to find a way to backup the machine while it is running and from what I see, this eliminates the disk clone utilities. All of the disk clone stuff I have seen for Linux requires that you reboot into a special live CD.

So my question is this, what is the best solution for backing up the system while it is running? Also, I don't really care about the OS config too much, I just want to be able to keep my stored files and my programs that I have installed on it.

Thanks

Comment: Hahaha! I think it is! But lets send this comment to `/dev/null` shall we?

Comment: Something tells me this needs a disclaimer, no idea why though

Comment: For the uninitiated, the previous comments are jokes... sorry guys

Answer (score 16):

The important directories are `/etc`, `/home`, `/var`, and `/srv`. You may want to add `/root`, and remove unneeded bits from `/var`.

`rsync` is good if you want the files to be directly accessible, `tar` is fine if you don't.

Comment: Ok thanks for that info. Are there any disk clone backups that support "live" backups? Backups that don't require me to shutdown or deal physically with the server (such as put a CD in).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/23965/lvm-snapshots-as-a-backup-strategy

Comment: what should not be backed-up in /var ?

Comment: `/var/cache` is usually a biggie.

Comment: the entire `/home` folder? What if i only do `.config` `.local` `.themes` & `.icons`, shouldn't that be enough? I really don't want all my eBooks and downloads which i have on an external drive anyway.

Comment: @Ashesh: In the end it's up to the person performing the backup to determine which files are truly important to them.

Comment: You are correct. But consider that a person wants only his settings intact, should there be any other folders according to you that must be backed up within `/home`?

Comment: @Ashesh: There are still many applications that store their configuration in a per-app (usually hidden) directory instead of one of the XDG-prescribed locations.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams about /etc/ /home/ and some parts in /var/.

But don't forget to save a list of the installed packages, so you know what programs was installed...

```
dpkg --get-selections > dpkg.list
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using backup2l to backup my Debian server (AFAIK Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian). If configured correctly it automates your backup, e.g. getting the dpkg selections, creating differential and incremental backups (depending on your settings) and storing it in an archive. A post backup hook triggers rsync which syncs my archive with a remote copy.

I'm backing up `/etc` `/var` (with some exclusions like caches), `/root`, `/home`.
Just think about what you have changed in addition to that and add it to the list. I for instance dump my sql databases in a special directory and save it, too.